# How to retrieve records from First table that don't have a reference in the Second table?

Tags: mysql

I have a database that contains a two tables, where these table have a relation between them, i want to retrieve records from first table that they don't have a reference in the second table ( the id's that appear in the first only)  ..

what is the sql command that do that ?

Comment: This is an excellent blog post to read http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2007/10/a-visual-explanation-of-sql-joins.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the NOT IN to specify that you're only interested in rows whose id has not been referenced from the other table

```
select * from table1 where table1.id NOT IN (select distinct referenced_id from table2)
```

Answer (score 2):

```
Select * From Table1
Where Table1.ReferenceID NOT IN (SELECT id From Table2)
```

Comment: That's an inefficient way of joining tables.

Answer (score 0):

Using `JOIN`:

```
SELECT * FROM
table_a
LEFT JOIN table_b ON table_a.id = table_b.a_id
HAVING table_b.some_column = NULL;
```

Using `NOT IN`:

```
SELECT * FROM
table_a 
WHERE table_a.id NOT IN (SELECT table_b.a_id from table_b);
```

If you are dealing with big tables, the left join will probably be much quicker.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT FirstTable.* 
FROM FirstTable
LEFT JOIN SecondTable
ON FirstTable.FirstTableId = SecondTable.FirstTableId
WHERE 1=1
AND SecondTable.SecondTableId IS NULL
```

Comment: Why do you have WHERE 1=1?  Since this is always true couldn't it be dropped to just be WHERE SecondTable.SecondTableId IS NULL ?  I'm asking only out of curiosity.